# web scraping with python exit code 0 problem

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to get some information from the AIIB project page. I wrote the following lines to get the names of the projects sine all the names are in the data6 class

```
from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.aiib.org/en/projects/list/index.html'
page = get(url)

bs = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

for name in bs.find_all('div', class_='data6'):
    print(offer)
```

When I try to run it I get "Process finished with exit code 0" but not output is listed i.e. the names I am trying to scrape. I got stuck at this point and I do not know how to move forward.

Also, I noticed that although the website has multiple pages, I think I do not need to find and go through all of the 18 project pages since all information is placed in one container. If I click on the "next page" button it will only change a class of the object, however the object itself retains its name and is identifiable. Is this correct? Or I do need to find how to somehow tell python to go through all of the project pages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The data is loaded from external source, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see the data. You can use following example how to load the data:

```py
import re
import json
import requests

url = "https://www.aiib.org/en/projects/list/.content/all-projects-data.js"

data = requests.get(url).text
data = re.search(r"(\[.*\])", data, flags=re.S).group(1)
data = json.loads(re.sub(r",\s*]", r"]", data, flags=re.S))

# uncomment to see all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for project in data:
    print(project["name"])
```

Prints:

```
India: Enel Green 300 MW Solar Project - Rajasthan
Egypt: Inclusive Growth for Sustainable Recovery DPF Program
Mongolia: Support for COVID-19 Vaccine Delivery in Mongolia under the Asia Pacific Vaccine Access Facility
China: Sinovation Disrupt Fund
Azerbaijan: Republic of Azerbaijan COVID-19 Active Response and Expenditure Support (CARES) Program
China: Liaoning Green Smart Public Transport Demonstration Project
Multicountry: Global Infrastructure Partners Emerging Markets Fund I (“GIP EM” or the “Fund”)
Indonesia: Emergency Response to COVID-19 Program - Additional Financing
Rwanda: Support to COVID-19 Economic Recovery Fund for Private Sector
India: Gujarat Education Infrastructure and Technology Modernization Program
Uzbekistan: Sirdarya 1,500MW CCGT Power Project
Rwanda: Rwanda Digital Acceleration Project (Digital Investment for Recovery, Resilience and Connectivity) 
India: West Bengal Electricity Distribution Grid Modernization Project
Belarus: Belarus Emergency Response and Public Healthcare Support Project
India: Chennai City Partnership: Sustainable Urban Services Program
Uzbekistan: Medium-size Cities Integrated Urban Development Project


...and so on.
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrej! Could you please explain to me what is going on in these two lines                                                                                                                                             `data = re.search(r"(\[.*\])", data, flags=re.S).group(1)
data = json.loads(re.sub(r",\s*]", r"]", data, flags=re.S))`   So I could iterate the code and get information on status, financing, year and sector?

Comment: @regneck7854 To get additional information you can uncomment  the ` print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))` and see what's inside the data. For example `project['status']`, `project['sector']` etc. The `re.sub` etc. is cleaning the JavaScript file to compatible Json form (to be able to parse it with `json` module)

Comment: thank you! I am trying to scrape the data with helium, it looks like it can detect the page source with the following code `from helium import *
url = 'https://www.aiib.org/en/projects/list/index.html'
browser = start_chrome(url, headless = True)

html = browser.page_source print(html)` However  if I type `names = find_all(S('.name6'))` it does not give any output. I am trying to circumvent using regex as I do not fully understand the syntax.

Comment: Ok, `from helium import *
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.aiib.org/en/projects/list/index.html'
browser = start_chrome(url, headless = True)

html = browser.page_source
names_list = find_all(S('.data3'))
names = [item.web_element.text for item in names_list]

print(names)` works fine